My 3D model in .glb is not being exported same as seen in blender view
I created a 3D scan from an external App. I imported the .glb file in blender and added a hue/saturation node to fix colours.
When I export the edited model in .GLB, it does not come out same as seen in Vlender viewer. My output model looks compressed and colours are still not right.
What am I doing wrong?
Blender view:

Exported model in .gltf viewer:

Shading tool Settings:

I am exporting it using Export > Glb/Gltf > Selected Objects and with Apply Modifiers selected.
